# Excel numberformat currency without symbol

Tags: excel, format, currency

If I select in Excel "currency" without symbol and press ok

[image]

And then open the cell format again, the category"currency" is lost.

[image]

Selecting different currency symbol will work.

Is there a solution to use the category "currency" but without a currency symbol?

There is the category "accounting" which I could use, but then I didn't get the negative numbers to appear in Red color. Maybee this is possible, maybee not.

Answer (score 0):

I think the option you selected in the Custom category should work perfectly for your requirements of (red if minus with no symbol). 
[Image of formated cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QNq5.png)